# Why after() method not works in a multi for loop?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am going to use the `after()` method in a multi `forloop`. The plan is to print every combined text at interval of one second.

But it runs directly to the end and only prints the last combined text. How can I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from Tkinter import *
import time

FirstList = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
SecondList = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
ThirdList = ["A" , "B" , "C"]

root = Tk()
root.title("Program")
root['background'] ='gray'

def command_Print():
    for i in range(0, len(FirstList), 1):
        for j in range(0, len(SecondList), 1):
            for k in range(0, len(ThirdList), 1):
                PrintText = FirstList[i] + SecondList[j] + ThirdList[k]
                Labelvar.set(PrintText)
                Label0.after(1000, lambda: command_Print)

Labelvar = StringVar()
Labelvar.set(u'original value')
Frame0 = Frame(root)
Frame0.place(x=0, y=0, width=100, height=50)
Label0 = Label(Frame0, textvariable=Labelvar, anchor='w')
Label0.pack(side=LEFT)

Frame_I = Frame(root)
Frame_I.place(x = 100, y = 0, width=100, height=70)
Button_I = Button(Frame_I, text = "Button" , width = 100, height=70, command = command_Print)
Button_I.place(x=0, y=0)
Button_I.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
Button_I.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what you want, you just want the cartestian product of your lists. You can use `itertools` for this instead of a nested forloop like you have, no need to re-invent the wheel since itertools already has this built-in and it's by far cleaner.

Here you go: (Not tested)

```
import itertools

PRODUCTS = itertools.product(FirstList, SecondList, ThirdList)

def show_next_product():

     try:
        LabelVar.set(next(PRODUCTS))
        root.last_after = root.after(1000, show_next_product)
     except StopIteration:
        LabelVar.set("Out of products.")
        root.after_cancel(root.last_after)
```

Also, the `StringVar` seems unnecessary. Unless you're doing something with `trace` method for StringVar's I've never seen the point in using them honestly.

You can just directly change the text by using `Label0['text'] = 'newtext'`, but that's personal preference of course. :)

Comment: Minor fix: You'd need `''.join(next(PRODUCTS))` to get a string, not `tuple`.